# URL string cannot pass to GA Custom Variables via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I am attempting to parse a url string to a custom variable in GA using javascript. 
The string that I want parsed is the value after the parameter etid=

So for example using **www.site.com/?etid=1234kks0**, the variable that gets returned should be **1234kkso**.

The code that I am using seems to work in the browser console when i recall the variable name, however it does not return in GA,

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}


var etid = getQueryVariable("etid");


_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',4,'user',etid,1]);
```

Comment: Does _setCustomVar even still work after everything has been migrated to Universal Analytics ? Maybe you should move to the new version of the tracking code and use a custom dimension instead.

Comment: UA is not an option at this stage unfortuantely.long story